# How to change Chr(10) to combine with delimiters?

Tags: split, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a field that can store multiple values :

```
Example:
10
20
30
```

How to change Chr(10) to combine with delimiters (such as commas)?

such as 10,20,30

```
itemno = itemno + Trim(Mid(Rec,3),5) + Chr(10) '10 20 30
doc.ITEMNO = itemno
item_no = Split(doc.ITEMNO(0) , Chr(10)
For i = 0 To UBound(item_no)
    'Here's code need to help~~~
Next
```

Comment: If it is a multivalue field, there should not be a Chr(10) as part of the field value. It is only there as a display option, not in storage.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz 
Umm.....so, How can I change the Chr(10) to ","?(let example to 10,20,30, not have Chr(10))?

Comment: You don't have to. If it is a multivalue field, there is no Chr(10) stored in the item.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Oh!!!Really??? But I really used the "Chr(10)" in the code, why you said there is no Chr(10) stored in the item? And the "itemno" I used, is dim as a variant.

Comment: You said it's multiple values, right?  If you wrote front-end code that puts in chr(10)s, they should be gone. In Notes and Domino, multiple values normally means that you defined separator characters in the form design and let the client processing automatically remove them and store each value in a separate element of the back-end array. Maybe you're not doing that, but then you do not really have multiple values; you just have a single value that has chr(10) inserted.

Comment: The way you can tell is by looking at the field values in the document properties dialog. If you look at the ITEMNO item on the second tab and you see only a single quoted string with all the values, then you have a single value and I guess your chr(10)s are still there. If you scroll and see multiple lines, with each line in its own pair of quotes, then it is a multi-value field and your Chr(10)s have been stripped.

Answer (score 1):

Use LotusScript function `Implode(sourceArray, delimiter)`. It concatenates all members of an Array of Strings and returns a string separated by the delimiter.

```
result = Implode(item_no, ", ")
```

`item_no` must be an array of Strings.

---

In case you have a String and want to replace all Chr(10) with ", " then use `Replace` instead:

```
result = Replace(item_string, chr(10), ", ")
```

You should consider that your newline can be Chr(13) instead or in addition of Chr(10). It depends on how the item was created/updated.

Comment: I changed your advice after I used your advice. The code still like I Edited......